# How to access Google fitness data in Managed Workflow (Expo Go)?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-fit-api, expo-go

i am currently working on a fitness app for a project on Expo Go , one of its features include Steps count too and i chose google data for the step counts . i managed to implement the sign in with google functionality , it returns the user info and the token too but i would like to ask if there’s a way i can access the fitness data too without switching to Bare Workflow. i simply want to read the activity data from google . Is it possible?

i spent days finding a way to Sign in with google on Expo Go but now i have no idea how to access Google fit data because most of the posts online are saying its only possible on bare workflow but i thought maybe there would be a way to do it now?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.